# Getting started with clang, LLVM, and running existing passes

Tags: llvm-clang

I am starting to work with LLVM, clang, and passes. This is a developed field, and I quickly become overwhelmed with the wealth of information out there. I was hoping someone could shed some light on these topics, with *just enough detail to understand the bigger picture* and just enough information to get started. Some of the details which I think would be useful are:

**Q1)** What is the relationship between LLVM and clang?

**Q2)** I know LLVM has a large set of existing static analysis techniques are these called passes?

**Q3)** What code representation format do I need to use to run a pass?

**Q4)** How do I run passes?

I know this is a very broad question. I am just looking for someone to give me enough information so that I have a footing and can get started fiddling with these tools.